# SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB()).train() MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, naivebayes

following is the code I am using in Natural Language processing:-

```
training_set = featuresets[:10000]
testing_set = featuresets[10000:]
MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
```

the above code is giving the following error: -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\siddharth.u\Documents\Natural Language Processing\Creating a module for Sentiment Analysis with NLTK\Creating a module for Sentiment Analysis with NLTK.py", line 103, in 
    MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
  File "D:\Users\siddharth.u\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 117, in train
    X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
  File "D:\Users\siddharth.u\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 230, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "D:\Users\siddharth.u\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 172, in _transform
    values.append(dtype(v))
MemoryError

Comment: Yeah sure. You got not enough memory. Look at your data-size and check the memory/space-complexity of the underlying classifier. Maybe you should use [an incremental / online approach](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.partial_fit).

Comment: thank you for your response....can you please help me on how to use partial_fit method on chunks of data with respect to the code i have used.